How do I find maximal quotients of subspaces of the vector spaces $V_i$?
Say I have linear maps $V_1 \xrightarrow{h} V_2 \xleftarrow{g}  V_3 \xrightarrow{f} V_4$. Assume $V_i$ are finite dimensional.
(1) I want to find maximal subspaces $W_i$ of $V_i$ such that in the diagram $W_1 \xrightarrow{h} W_2 \xleftarrow{g} W_3 \xrightarrow{f} W_4$ each map is surjective.
(2) I then want to find maximal quotients $\bar{W}_i$ of $W_i$ such that each map in the diagram $\bar{W}_1 \xrightarrow{\bar{h}} \bar{W}_2 \xleftarrow{\bar{g}} \bar{W}_3 \xrightarrow{\bar{f}} \bar{W}_4$is injective.

My answer to (1) is: $h^{-1}(\mathrm{Im\,} g) \xrightarrow{h} \mathrm{Im\,}h  \cap \mathrm{Im\,}g \xleftarrow{g} g^{-1}(\mathrm{Im\,} h) \xrightarrow{f} \mathrm{Im\,} f$.
For (2), I have: $\frac{h^{-1}(\mathrm{Im\,} g)}{\mathrm{ker\,} h} \xrightarrow{\bar{h}} \mathrm{Im\,}h  \cap \mathrm{Im\,}g \xleftarrow{\bar{g}} \frac{g^{-1}(\mathrm{Im\,} h)}{\mathrm{ker\,} g + \mathrm{ker\,} f} \xrightarrow{\bar{f}} \mathrm{Im\,} f$.
Is this correct
Edit: For (1) I am pretty sure the solution is correct. For (2), I am not sure if I satisfy the maximality condition.

"Is this proof correct?" is too broad or missing context. Instead, the question must identify precisely which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so. (Cited from tag:solution-verification) Please edit your question to add the above-mentioned context. Also, the questions in your title and body are not equivalent: In general the maps won't remain surjective in step (2). Which version of the question are you interested in?

Thank you, @anankElpis. I did not know that the maps will not remain surjective in (2). If I require that the vector spaces $V_i$ be finite dimensional, will that problem go away?

@anankElpis: I have now added where I have doubts in my solution.

I guess in the answer to (1) the rightmost space should be $f(g^{-1}\mathrm{Im,} h)$  instead of $\mathrm{Im,} f$.

(1) Clearly, $W_2\subset h(V_1)\cap g(V_3)$, so $W_1\subset h^{-1}(h(V_1)\cap g(V_3))=h^{-1}(g(V_3))$ and $W_3\subset g^{-1}(h(V_1)\cap g(V_3))=g^{-1}(h(V_1))$, and so $W_4\subset f(g^{-1}(h(V_1)))$. On the other hand, it is easy to see that we can put all inclusions to be equalities.
(2) For each natural $i\le 4$ let $K_i$ be the minimal kernel from $W_i$. Let $K_f$, $K_g$, and $K_h$ be the kernels of the maps $f$, $g$, and $h$, respectively, from the diagram $W_1 \xrightarrow{h} W_2 \xleftarrow{g} W_3 \xrightarrow{f} W_4$. Then $K_1\supset K_h$ and $K_3\supset K_g+K_f$. On the other hand, as far as I understood the construction of the diagram $\bar{W}_1 \xrightarrow{\bar{h}} \bar{W}_2 \xleftarrow{\bar{g}} \bar{W}_3 \xrightarrow{\bar{f}} \bar{W}_4$, it seems that we can put all inclusions to be equalities.
